# Remove Query after reloading with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, url

I am making a todo list as part of a project. The user will be able to add a task using PHP file and the file will then redirect the user to a page using the header function with a URL query

The header function redirect is:

```
header('Location: http://localhost:8888/ECode/index.php?status=success');
// the query can also be ?status=error or ?status=sqlerror or ?status=resulterror
```

Depending on the status I will echo a message like so:

```
if(isset($_GET['status'])){
    if($_GET['status'] === "success")
    {
        echo "<p class='status success'>Action Was Successful!</p>";
    } 
    else if ($_GET['status'] === "connerror")
    {
        echo "<p class='status error'>We Have Made A Mistake In The Program! Please Contact thepurplelounge1@gmail.com And Title The Message \"ConnError\"!</p>";
    } 
    else if ($_GET['status'] === "resulterror")
    {
        echo "<p class='status error'>We Have Made A Mistake In The Program! Please Contact thepurplelounge1@gmail.com And Title The Message \"ResultError\"!</p>";
    }
    else if ($_GET['status'] === "emptyName")
    {
        echo "<p class='status error'>The Name Field Was Empty, Fill All Input! If There Is An Error Contact thepurplelounge1@gmail.com And Title The Message \"EmptyName\"!</p>";
    }
}
```

This is fine if there really is an error. However, when the user reloads the page, the query will still be part of the URL.

is there a way I can check if the user clicked the reload button or if they were redirected to the URL with the query?

This can also be through Javascript functions but I prefer doing it in PHP. Obviously, if you know a solution using Javascript please suggest it.

Comment: Create a flash message. In short place the message that need to be displayed in a session variable, check if the session variable exists on the page u want to display it, if it exists store it in a variable to output and remove session variable

Comment: I will look into, thank you for the suggestion!